# Заполнение таблицы php при изменении combobox на этой же странице

Tags: php, html, table, combobox

Есть запрос который заполняет combobox на сайте. Хочу чтобы при выборе какой либо позиции заполнялась таблица. 
код заполения combobox

```
<?php
            $q = intval($_GET['q']);

            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','M44naxu44','BRS');
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            mysqli_query($query);
            if (!$con) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM grou where prav= {$_SESSION['prav']}";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $name = [];
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $val[]=$row['id_group'];
                $names[] = $row['sok'];

            }
            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
            <form method="post">
            <select name="group" onchange="selectChanged(this.value);">
                <?php foreach($names as $name){  ?>
                    <option value=<?php echo $val;?>><?php echo $name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </form>
```

код заполнения таблицы

```
<tbody>
            <?php
            $group = null;
            if(isset($_POST['group'])){
                $group = $_POST['group'];

                $sql = "SELECT fio.*, grou.* FROM fio JOIN grou  WHERE fio.id_group = grou.id_group and sok='{$name}'";
                $query = R::getAll($sql);
                echo $sql;
            }
            foreach ($query as $item):
                //var_dump($item);

                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center"><?= $item['FIO'] ?></td>
                                    <td contenteditable class="text-center"><?php if($item['sem1']==""){echo '0';}?></td>
                                    <td contenteditable class="text-center"><?php if($item['sem1prop']==""){echo '0';}?></td>
                                    <td contenteditable class="text-center"><?php if($item['sem1propu']==""){echo '0';}?></td>                                    

                                </tr>

            <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: используйте ajax

Comment: @ArchDemon Не могли бы подсказать что к чему

Comment: Проще найти в поисковике. Но смысл такой. Вешаете js'ом обработчик на изменение выпадающего списка. В обработчике делаете запрос через ajax, в качестве параметра передавая выбранный элемент списка. Полученные от ajax данные выводите в какой-нибудь элемент